Z-Score and Z-Test
I dont understand how / the purpose of the sqrt(n) in the Z-Test works.  A Z-Score of .7 seems good in that the sample mean is less than one standard deviation of the population mean and the p-value is .7580 per the table.  But when multiplied by say the sqrt(50) it becomes a large number like 4.9 and the value in the table is very small and I think "if p is low Ho must go". What am I doing/thinking wrong?

You are doing nothing wrong.
Essentially, the larger the sample size gets, the more you expect the sample mean to be close to the hypothesis mean.  So for the same difference between the sample mean and the hypothesis mean, you are more surprised (and so more likely to reject the null hypothesis) when you have a larger sample size. Getting a larger $Z$-value in absolute terms by using the square root of the sample size to reduce the standard error of the sample mean, and so a smaller $p$-value, is the analytical part of this.
The $Z$-test looks at the distribution of the difference between the sample mean $\bar x$ and the hypothesis mean $\mu_0$. To get $Z$ you then divide this by the standard error of the sample mean to give something which under the null hypothesis has a standard normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$ (or is close to that if you assume the shape of the distribution of the sample mean is approximately normal), and this is what you test.  If you know the population standard deviation under the null hypothesis is $\sigma_0$, then the standard error of the sample mean is $\frac{\sigma_0}{\sqrt{n}}$.  So you look at $Z=\frac{\bar x - \mu_0}{\frac{\sigma_0}{\sqrt{n}}} = \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\bar x - \mu_0}{\sigma_0}\right)$.
Suppose you had a null hypothesis that the random variable in question had a normal distribution with mean $300$ and standard deviation $10$:

if you saw a single observation of $307$, you would not be very surprised:  there is about a $75.8\%$ probability you would see an observation less than $307$ (and a $51.6\%$ probability you would see an observation between $293$ and $307$) leaving a probability of $24.2\%$ (or $48.4\%$) of seeing a more extreme value under the null hypothesis

if you saw $50$ observations with a sample mean of $307$, you would be very surprised and could doubt the null hypothesis:  the variance of the sample mean would be $\frac{10^2}{50}$, and so the standard error of the sample mean would be $\frac{10}{\sqrt{50}}\approx 1.4142$ so $307$ is about $4.95$ standard errors above the hypothesis mean, and thus there is about a $99.999963\%$ probability you would see a sample mean less than $307$ (and a $99.999926\%$ probability you would see a sample between $293$ and $307$) leaving very small probabilities (i.e. $p$-values) of seeing a more extreme value under the null hypothesis



Thanks.  So it seems with a sample size of 50 my Z-score has to be less than .277 before I reject u = uo in a two-tailed 95% confidence test. Meaning my sample is in question or the population mean/sd is in question.  That's a sample mean only .277 away from the population mean.  Right?

@DavidAustin In effect yes-ish, but in a real sense no.  Your $Z$-score comes after you have included the $\sqrt{50}$ term.  So you want the sample mean to be more than $1.96$ standard errors of the mean away from the hypothesis population mean, i.e. $|Z|>1.96$, to reject the null hypothesis at $5%$.  With a sample size of $50$ that is equivalent to the sample mean to be more than $0.277$ population standard deviations away from the hypothesis population mean as you suggest, but it is doing the calculation in the wrong order and may not help you with more complicated problems.
